# How to stabilize the overall appearance of a Manipulate widget?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, gui-construction

**NB:** I've seen other post's that ask similar questions, but I haven't found one whose answers address the problems described here.

---

The code below is a ***very artificial*** example that illustrates the problem.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {{k, 0}, -0.00001, 0.00001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , ContentSize -> {300, 200}
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

As one moves the slider, the widget's appearance becomes completely unstable: the widget's overall dimensions fluctuate, the relative positioning of its contents also fluctuates, scrollbars pop in and out of existence, etc.

How can this thing be stabilized?

---

Some important notes:

- I have expressly placed the controls to the left to bring out the problem with the fluctuating label width.  Please take the left-placement of the controls as a given.
- It's fine with me if the number of digits of precision shown changes as the slider is displaced, as long as this does not result in a horizontal shifting of the plot area.  IOW, there should be enough extra space for as many digits of precision may appear.
- I saw no difference with either `PreserveImageOptions->True` or `PreserveImageOptions->False`.

Comment: I think you'll have to be very explicit about controls, e.g. try `Labeled[Control[{k, -0.0001, 0.0001}], Pane[Dynamic@k, ImageSize -> 50,ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"], Right]` in place of `{{k,0}....}`

Comment: Not quite what you seek, but this helps:  `Appearance -> "Open"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
    Row[{"k  ",
         Manipulator[Dynamic[k], {-0.00001, 0.00001}],
         Spacer[10],
         Pane[Dynamic[k], 100]}],
    ContentSize -> {300, 200}, 
    ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the undocumented method option `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {{k, 0}, -0.00001, 0.00001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , ContentSize -> {300, 200}
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
 , Method -> "ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> (Pane[#1, 300] &)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to build the `Control` by yourself and fix the size.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 Control[Row[{"k", Slider[Dynamic[k], {-0.00001, 0.00001}], 
    Dynamic[Pane[k, 80]]}, Spacer[5]]],
 ContentSize -> {300, 200},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```